# Select table value by range

Tags: sql, oracle

In my table I have the primary key `id`. It is a two byte varchar type.
If the `id` is from 00 to 89 then it returns a set of data, otherwise returns different data. My query in the stored procedure is

```
BEGIN
select * from MyTable where (id like '0%' or
                             id like '1%' or
                             id like '2%' or
                             id like '3%' or
                             id like '4%' or
                             id like '5%' or
                             id like '6%' or
                             id like '7%' or
                             id like '8%') 
                             and status = 'active'
union all
select * from MyTable where id like '9%' and status='inactive'
END
```

My question is how can I improve it? May I convert the string to number then using `>89` or `<90`?

Comment: Is it intentional, that the `%` is missing after the `9` in the second subquery?

Comment: You are right, typo. Corrected it already.

Comment: Also there is a stray `or` after `'8%'`, and an extra bracket after `'active'`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use regular expressions:

```
select * from MyTable
where REGEXP_LIKE(id, '^[0-8][0-9]') and status='active'
or REGEXP_LIKE(id, '^9[0-9]') and status='inactive'
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I just found a case in which `id` is `0A` something like.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
select * from mytable
where  ( id <  '9' and status = 'active' )
or     ( id >= '9' and status = 'inactive' )
```